# Could we say "discuss future work"?

Tags: meaning, grammar, american-english, academia

I am writing my thesis. I have a sentence

> Finally, we conclude the thesis and discuss future work in Section 6.

My friend told me that "discuss future work" was not appropriate, and I could not find the usage of
"discuss future work" on the internet. Shall I adopt "discuss the directions for future work"?
I cannot distinguish "discuss future work" with "discuss the directions for future work".
Could you give me some suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suppose 'discuss' isn't in itself informal in register, and of course theses must not be, but insisting on a more precise 'discuss ideas and plans for future work' rather than the deleted form 'discuss future work' seems a little draconian. The use of 'discuss' is totally acceptable: << **discuss** ... (3): to present in detail for examination or consideration >> [[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/discuss)]

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks for your suggestions! Your suggestions help me a lot! I will adopt your suggestions!

Comment: Your friend _may_ benefit from seeing the M-W definition of the appropriate sense of 'discuss' – it isn't the usual 'chat together about' sense – but it might well have just been the fact that future work isn't a given (ie it may _not_ take place) that concerns them.

Comment: I’ve seen worse. (And I’ve seen a lot of PhD theses.) But do you really need to say it?  “Finally we conclude the thesis.” is short and direct. And final. (The authorial “we” is not to my taste, but you are probably right to play safe.) If you discuss future possible work in your conclusion, the reader will discover that when he reads it. I usually told my students to keep that short, but prepare thoroughly to be able to talk about it in the oral exam. Depends on the system.

Comment: @David Your advice helps me a lot! I will keep that short!